# parse a JSON file with jQuery and fill an array for later use

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, getjson, lightgallery

for lightGallery jQuery plugin I want to fill a variable called DynamicEl by using a JSON file with the follwing structure:

```
    {
  "images":[
    {
      "src":"img/image1.jpg",
      "subHtml":"<h4>subtext1</h4>"
    },
    {
      "src":"img/image2.jpg",
      "subHtml":"<h4>subtext2</h4>"
    },
    {
      "src":"img/image3.jpg",
      "subHtml":"<h4>subtext3</h4>"
    }
  ]
}
```

To avoid asynchronous call issues of jQuery function $.getJSON I used the following piece of code:

```
var dummy = $.getJSON("js/gallery.json");
dummy.done(function(data) {
  var dataArray = [];
  $.each(data.images, function (index, value) {
        dataArray.push(value.src);
        dataArray.push(value.subHtml);
  })
  console.log("dataArray "+dataArray);
});
```

In JS console I can see the values of these objects but I can't use them to fill a global variable called myImages. If I try this variable will show [object Object] in console.

I tried converting this object with return(String(dataArray); and return(JSON.stringify(dataArray); without success.

Last but not least I tried the following with the same wrong result

```
    MyImages = [];
    MyImages = dummy.done(function(data) {
      var dataArray = [];
      $.each(data.images, function (index, value) {
            dataArray.push("\'src\'\:\ '"+value.src+"\',\'subHtml\'\: \'"+value.subHtml+"\'");
      })
      return(String(dataArray));
    }));
    console.log("myImages" +myImages);
});
```

As final result I need an array containing src and htmlSub values in this format

```
DynamicEl: [{'src': 'img/image1.jpg', 'subHtml': '<h4>subText1</h4>'},{{'src': 'img/image2.jpg', 'subHtml': '<h4>subText2</h4>'}]
```

How can I achieve this goal? I'm out of ideas how to get "string"-values out of the loaded JSON file into a global array. Thank you in advance.

Comment: sorry, i dont see the problem. i just coded your point here http://dojo.telerik.com/atuNO   and it is working. feel free to make any change where you believe you didn't do the same thing

Comment: `If I try this variable will show [object Object] in console` this is because you're appending the object to a string, hence it will be coerced to a string too. Just do `console.log(dataArray);` to see the object in the console.

Comment: @Rory 
yes, in console.log this dataArray element inside the defered call shows the expexted content. But not the myImages array. In console.log it shows "object Object". That seems to be an issue because I need the array loaded from JSON to create a string which I can handover to call of lightGallery as value of DynamicEl.

Comment: tried the following code with the result `{"ready.state","1"}` showed in an alert box.  `var dummy = $.getJSON("js/gallery.json");myImages = dummy.done(function(data) {
  var dataArray = [];
  $.each(data.images, function (index, value) {
        dataArray.push("\'src\'\:\ '"+value.src+"\',\'subHtml\'\: \'"+value.subHtml+"\'");
  })
  return(dataArray);
});
alert(JSON.stringify(myImages, null, 4));`